# Working with negative numbers in formulas using VBA 2013 Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have some software I have written in Excel 2013, and have a recent issue that has occurred, and not sure how to approach a solution. I'm thinking of using VBA to check for a negative (-) number in a cell, but then what to do with that number once it is located. In one column, I have "Start", second column is "Received", third is "Used", fourth is "Close", and fifth is "Cost". The starting column puts in the starting inventory for the day, and this number changes daily. If a user puts a number in the "Received" or "Used" column, the "Close" column calculates the data as: Start + Received - Used. Sometimes, a user may put to large of a number in the "Used" column, so on the next report, the user puts a negative (-) number to "replace" the unused inventory. I need to be able to replace the inventory, based on a negative number, and adjust the cost, as the software also figures the cost of the "Used" inventory, and puts this in the "Cost" column. Can anyone help me with this issue? Right now, I just have formulas in the spreadsheet cells, but nothing to look for the negative numbers, and if so, then perform an algorithm of such to adjust the inventory(make greater), and cost(adjust for over-charge). Much help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Is it an option to use a *custom Data Validation rule* on the `Used` column to forbid entering a number that exceeds `Start + Received`?

Comment: Please post a sample of what your data looks like now and what you want it to look like. Your description is a bit verbose and difficult to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just if IF

`=IF([VALUE]<0,"",[VALUE])`

Comment: The "Rec" & "Used" columns allow for user input. The "Close" column calculates what's left, and through a macro for start of a new report, the macro copies the "Close" of one day, to the "Start" of the next. The "Close" column is the only one with a formula, besides the "Cost" column. "Close" column calculates as: = Start + Rec - Used. Conditional formatting may work to a point, only that if the user puts the max "Start" inventory, then tries to replace that inventory. Example: Start=50, Rec=0, and Used=50(which should be 10, but user made an error). So the Close=0, but should be 40....

Comment: I think what I'm trying to do is loop through the range of cells to look for any negative numbers, but how would you search for negative values in a range of cells? This code will let me search through each cell, but then do what `Sub LoopRange()

    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rRng As Range

    Set rRng = DMR_Master.Range("S22:S50")

    For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
        'process to look for negative numbers here
    Next rCell

End Sub`